# SFDX Authorize an Org failed to run

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdx

When running the VSC>SFDX command "**SFDX: Authorize an Org**", I am getting the error: "**SFDX: Authorize an Org failed to run**" (I am using VSC on a Mac).

VSC>Terminal>Output displays the following messages:

Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org
20:03:10.886 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias DEV --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
/Users/eduardo/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: line 16: /Users/eduardo/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/../7.132.0-6621068/bin/sfdx: No such file or directory
20:03:10.912 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias DEV --instanceurl https://test.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
ended with exit code 1

Any idea of how can I possibly resolve this issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you Cezu. After re-installing Salesforce CLI and running the command sfdx from the Terminal window, I am still getting this error: "/Users/eduardo/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: line 16: /Users/eduardo/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/../7.132.0-6621068/bin/sfdx: No such file or directory". Any clue of what is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall sfdx-cli i have similiar problem on mac and reinstall helps me try additionaly `sfdx update`. Sometimes there can be a problem with browser which is block and causes problems. Do you have same problem when you run a same command in terminal ?

BR